# How do I get a subset of a Backbone.Collection?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

Given this collection -

```
{"education":
[
    {
        "school":{
            "name":"Maxwell",
            "type":"Secondary",
            "teachers": [
                {"name":"Mrs. Smith","subject":"Chemistry"},
                {"name":"Mr. Jones","subject":"Calculus"}
            ]
        }
    },{
        "school":{
            "name":"Bright",
            "type":"Elementry",
            "teachers": [
                {"name":"Mr. Anthony","subject":"Reading"},
                {"name":"Mrs. Bates","subject":"Social Studies"}
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

I am trying to return all of the school items so that I can display the names in my template.

Given this code -

```
schools = [];
filtered = this.filter(function (item) {
        return (
                item.get('school') !== ''
        )
});       
_.each(filtered, function(k,v) {
    _.each(k.attributes.models, function (k2, v2) {                 
        schools.push(k2.get('school'));
    });
});
colSchools = new Backbone.Collection(schools);
```

This gets the job done, but it doesn't seem very efficient, or really the correct way to do things.

I tried looping on *this* instead of filtered, and I get an error that *k is undefined*.  My question I guess is two part - why would that return *k is undefined* and what am I missing about grabbing the subset of the education collection?  I feel like the nested loop is excess work that doesn't need to happne.  It could be that I am misinterpreting how Backbone handles collections, or is this really the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: What does `this` refer to? I don't see anything that relates `schools` to `this`.

Comment: I should have been more complete in my question.  this refers to the collection, as the 2nd set of code is part of a function within my backbone.collection.extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck is what you're looking for:

```
var stooges = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Curly", age: 60},
  {name: "Larry", age: 70},
  {name: "Moe", age: 80}
]);

var names = stooges.pluck("name");

alert(JSON.stringify(names));
```

If you try it this should alert `["Curly","Larry","Moe"]`

EDIT: sorry I didn't spot the nested level, but since pluck it's just an application of map you could do something like this:

```
stooges.map(function(model){
  return model.get('school').name;
});
```

Comment: In this particular instance, doing `this.pluck('school')` will return undefined, as your example is not the same as mine.  Yours is a simple JSON object with no hierarchy, whereas in my example, I need the values of school, which is descendant of `education`.  What I want to know is there a quicker way to capture the values deep within the hierarchy of a Collection, or do I have to loop through the collection as I have done in the question?

Comment: I've updated my answer, sorry about that, does this help you?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite there yet. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LneNG/3/ I tried a couple variations, one using code that I have in my application, and two variations of your edited example.  In both `map` calls the result is `undefined`, and when I used the suggestion of appending `.name` to the `get`, I get `m.get(...) is undefined`.  I feel like it's something simple I am overlooking here.  Am I going at this from the wrong angle?  Is it not possible to delve deep into a Collection as I want to, similar to using xpath to get elements buried in an XML object?

Comment: Here is what I got, I don't think one can go much better without changing the data structure: http://jsfiddle.net/LneNG/9/ Is this fine with you?